# Meaning of 江山错落. 人间星火

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary, sentence-structure

Those two phrases are from this song on YouTube “礼仪之邦”.  I have high confidence that I understand the 人间星火.  But I am not quite sure about the 江山错落.

Here is Google’s version: The country is scattered. The world is sparkling.

If you need to explain both within the context of each other or within the context of the song itself that would be fine.

Comment: This reminds me of a couple of lines from a poem "The Second Coming" by W.B. Yeats, which reads, "Things fall apart; The centre cannot hold; Mere anarchy is loosed upon the world"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [錯落](https://pedia.cloud.edu.tw/Entry/Detail/?title=%E9%8C%AF%E8%90%BD)

> 解釋：交錯紛雜 (crisscrossing, various and numerous)

Base on this entry, we can deduct:

錯 = 交錯 = crisscrossing (of rivers)

落 = 起落 = up and down (of mountains)

江山错落 = rivers crisscrossing, mountains various and numerous / the nation's various landscapes are intertwined

人间星火 (star lights of the people's land) sounds like an impression of a view of the people's land from above at night -- countless households' tiny lights in the dark look like a starry night

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we can translate the two phrases word by word, as they are delivering an artistic message through singing.

The songwriter is trying to draw a vivid scenery in the listener's mind - at a star-covered evening standing on the hill looking down on the mountain surrounded village below, the scattered lights are glowing; alongside the village, the lazy water is slowly flowing in the river, so calm and peacefully beauty.

Wish this makes sense.

Comment: Great interpretation!

Comment: @Emily J Thanks for giving me the passing grade on my poor English and your compliment :)